# How can I validate the credentials in my database using Spring security and Restful web services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, basic-authentication

I'm very new to Spring security. I want to create a Spring security application with Basic Authentication and RestFul Webservices. Also I'm using **Spring Data JPA.**

I have gone through some examples over the internet. Most of them have a the Login UI form in the spring application itself. Also it is not validating the credentials from the data base.

But my case: I have a separate UI application, from my client application I'll send a login url (Restful api) call. I want to consume the request from my Spring application and the credentials should be validated from the database.

Comment: You'll have to implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`. See this https://github.com/pallavJha/EventApp/blob/master/event-webapp/src/main/java/pl/event/myWebApp/service/user/UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

Comment: How did you get on with the help given below, Prince?

Answer (score 7):

## Method 1

Simple way to configure **`Spring Security`** to authenticate against a credential on database, you can use the `jdbcAuthentication()` method. The minimal configuration required
is as follows:

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    
      auth
       .jdbcAuthentication()
       .dataSource(dataSource);

}
```

The only thing you must configure is a **DataSource** so that it’s able to access your database.

This minimal configuration will work with some assumptions about your
database schema. It expects that certain tables exist where *user data* will be kept.

More specifically, the following snippet of code from Spring Security’s internals shows the

SQL queries that will be performed when looking up user details:

[JdbcDaoImpl](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java#L118)

```
public static final String DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = "select username,password,enabled "
            + "from users " + "where username = ?";


public static final String DEF_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = "select username,authority "
            + "from authorities " + "where username = ?";


public static final String DEF_GROUP_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY = "select g.id, g.group_name, ga.authority "
            + "from groups g, group_members gm, group_authorities ga "
            + "where gm.username = ? " + "and g.id = ga.group_id "
            + "and g.id = gm.group_id";
```

The first query retrieves a user’s username, password, and whether or not they’re
enabled. This information is used to authenticate the user. The next query looks up the
user’s granted authorities for authorization purposes, and the final query looks up authorities granted to a user as a member of a group.

If you dont want to stick with default database structure that Spring Security enforce you can do this

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true from <tbl_name> where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, 'ROLE_ADMIN' from <tbl_name> where username=?");
}
```

In this case, you’re only overriding the authentication and basic authorization
queries. But you can also override the group authorities query by calling groupAuthoritiesByUsername()
with a custom query.

When overriding the default schema you need to follow to the basic contract of the queries. One this to notice here is that these queries accept only username as there parameter. The authorities query selects zero or more rows containing the username and a granted authority. And the group authorities query selects zero or more rows each with a group ID, group name, and an authority.

## Method 2 Implement UserDetailsService

You’ll need to implement [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) interface.

All you need to do is implement the `loadUserByUsername()` method to find a user given the user’s username. `loadUserByUsername()` then returns a [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) object representing the given user.

Basic Implementation

```
public class SomeUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final SomeRepository someRepository;

    public SomeUserService(SomeRepository someRepository) {
        this.someRepository = someRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserClass userObject = someRepository.findByUsername(username);
        
        if (userObject != null) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            
            return new User(
                userObject.getUsername(),
                userObject.getPassword(),
                authorities
            );
        }
        
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            "User '" + username + "' not found.");
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(new SomeUserService(someRepository));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this article, it describes how to perform login using REST endpoint:
http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security

You can use credentials from database by modifying authentication provider to something like:

```
<authentication-provider> 
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
        users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?"/>
</authentication-provider>
```

or, as  Obi Wan - PallavJha wrote, implement UserDetailService and plug it in using

```
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="YourUserDetailService" />
```